# Server Sent Events in Laravel

Tags: laravel, http, websocket, pusher

I want to use Server Sent events in Laravel and not websockets. How can I hook server sent events up to Laravels event broadcasting functionality? I would like to maintain a similar experience to using websockets in Laravel if possible. Would it be possible to keep using Pusher channels as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit of websockets is that it allows you to relay real-time updates from the backend to the front-end and make client-side events appear in real time. Therefore I would say that you need websockets. From my own exprience, Pusher is excellent for this.

Comment: Do you think websockets are still useful for less frequent events, and events which originate from server only and not viceversa? I have read about problems with websockets having trouble with firewalls and draining batteries on phones. Do you think these are real issues in 2020?

Comment: Websockets are to facilitate events that happen on the client-side. Lets assume you're selling something on an exchange. Websockets ensure that if someone buys your product, everyone else sees that purchase in real time, in order to prevent stale information. Conversely, server side events are used to send you an email confirming that someone bought your product. Server side events are for events that eminate from the server and require the server to broadcast them.

Comment: And in regards to firewalls and batteries. I'm not too sure, I can only guess, but I would argue that websockets would drain batteries more- albeit by how much I'm not too sure eat all. As it requires your device to be constantly subscribed to a channel and listening for incoming events. Requires extra processing power etc.